# OH-SCM-009: Error occurred while sync. No files checked in

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I try to migrate TFS 2012 to Visual Studio online. I use the tool OpsHub v1.1.0.005 but I received the following error message:

OH-SCM-009: Error occurred while sync. No files checked in.

Here is a sample of the log file:

> 2015-04-19 19:24:33,072 [22] DEBUG [De-bug]Conflict Count: 1
>
> 2015-04-19 19:24:33,072 [22] DEBUG [De-bug | Conflict]
>   Message:TF203057: Cannot check in the rename change for folder
>   $/Pueblo/Main/Service/Dispatch because there are files or folders in
>   this folder with pending rename or delete changes. You must check in
>   the rename and delete changes together.
>
> 2015-04-19 19:24:33,072 [22] DEBUG [De-bug | Conflict] Is
>   Resolveable?:False
>
> 2015-04-19 19:24:33,072 [22] DEBUG [De-bug | Conflict]
>   Item:$/Pueblo/Main/Service/Dispatch
>
> 2015-04-19 19:24:33,072 [22] DEBUG [De-bug]Note Failures Count: 0
>
> 2015-04-19 19:24:33,072 [22] DEBUG [De-bug]Policy Failures Count: 0
>
> 2015-04-19 19:24:33,165 [11] DEBUG run cnt : 0
>
> 2015-04-19 19:24:33,181 [11] DEBUG suite cnt : 0
>
> 2015-04-19 19:24:33,181 [11] DEBUG result cnt : 0
>
> 2015-04-19 19:24:43,680 [22] DEBUG Exception in thread of CheckinALL
>   process.
>
> 2015-04-19 19:24:44,382 [27] ERROR Error occured in thread of
>   CheckinAll:No files checked in.    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Client.ReportCheckInConflictsFailuresAndThrow(Workspace
>   workspace, CheckinResult checkinResult, Failure[] conflicts, Failure[]
>   failures, Boolean noAutoResolve, Int32 operationId)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace.CheckInInternal(WorkspaceCheckInParameters
>   parameters, Int32 operationId)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace.CheckIn(WorkspaceCheckInParameters
>   checkinParameters)    at
>   Service.Adapters.TFSCheckinWorkspaceContext.checkin(String comment,
>   WorkItemCheckinInfo[] workItemChanges, List1 otherCheckInProperties,
>   String checkinUser) in f:\Ashish Docs\Checkouts\OVSMU
>   Branch\OpsHubV2\TFSWCFServiceSource\Service\Service\TFSVersionControl\AdapterComponents\TFSCheckinWorkspaceContext.cs:line
>   2372    at Service.Adapters.TFSVCAdapter.checkIn(List1 checkinItems,
>   String checkinComment, String checkinUser, List1 workitemId, List1
>   otherCheckInProperties) in f:\Ashish Docs\Checkouts\OVSMU
>   Branch\OpsHubV2\TFSWCFServiceSource\Service\Service\TFSVersionControl\AdapterComponents\TFSVCAdapter.cs:line
>   123    at
>   com.opshub.tfs.test.TFSWebService.<>c__DisplayClass2.b__0()
>   in f:\Ashish Docs\Checkouts\OVSMU
>   Branch\OpsHubV2\TFSWCFServiceSource\Service\Service\TFSWebService.cs:line
>   692 2015-04-19 19:24:44,850 [27] ERROR Error : No files checked in.
>   at com.opshub.tfs.test.TFSWebService.CheckinAllStatus(String
>   authToken) in f:\Ashish Docs\Checkouts\OVSMU
>   Branch\OpsHubV2\TFSWCFServiceSource\Service\Service\TFSWebService.cs:line
>   736

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue is fixed in a new internal build of OpsHub v1.2.0.000

This is the procedure to install the new version:

1) Delete the all the Projects in your Visual Studio Online Instance which you failed to migrate or encounter error  in earlier attempt.

2) Re-create all the deleted project in step 1

3) Delete all the content of O: drive (as well as any other additional drive that has been mapped by the OpsHub utility)

4) Open Visual Studio (on the same machine) and connect to VSO. In Source Control Explorer, under Workspaces, delete all the workspace with name starting with "OH-*******".

5) Close all TFS products (Visual Studio, MTM etc) and delete all contents of 
    %localappdata%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\3.0\Cache
    %localappdata%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache
    %localappdata%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache

6) Uninstall the current version of migration utility and Delete the  "C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility" folder if found.

7) Install the Version of migration utility

8) Configure and start migrating you projects

Comment: Still happens with OpsHub 2.0.0.0 Free.