# OH-SCM-009: Error occurred while sync. No files checked in. For migration tool version 1.3.000B000

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I know that this question has been answered in another post and solved for version v1.2.0.000 of OpsHub: [OH-SCM-009: Error occurred while sync. No files checked in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29746918/oh-scm-009-error-occurred-while-sync-no-files-checked-in).
But the thing is that it is still a problem. I use OpsHub v1.3.000B000.
I have tried on two different PCs and the migration halts, showing this error.
What shall I do to successfully proceed with the migration?

Comment: Getting it with the new 2.0.0.0 version as well.